# Falang, add custom component

Tags: xml, joomla

How can I add a new component to Falang.

I am looking for information here: http://www.joomprod.com/integration-with-others-components/falang.html

But I have no idea how looks an XML for install it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a content elements file. But you might want to take a look at https://www.neno-translate.com it looks like it can translate any component.